# Is it possible to avoid PHP string validation with malformed UTF-8 string?

Tags: php, encoding

Some of the old PHP string functions for example `explode()` are working with UTF-8 strings, but they don't work properly on malformed UTF-8 strings. Is this a security issue? Is it possible to avoid string validation with malformed UTF-8 strings somehow?

It is hard to make a list of this functions. I think every core PHP string function is affected somehow. For example strpos does not give the right position in a string, strlen, does not give the right length. So I guess htmlentities, htmlspecialchars, etc... are affected as well, but it is more complicated, because some of them has an UTF-8 flag, some of them is not UTF-8 compatible, like strpos, some of them does not work with malformed UTF-8, etc... I can do a search after I have a working example, so that's what I am looking for.

It is enough for me for instance something like:

- send 2 malformed string to the server, which in theory I cannot check with these functions
- concat them with implode, and get something malicious, for example XSS.

Is this possible? I don't understand fully how UTF-8 or how malformed UTF-8 works...

Comment: add an example?

Comment: Yes, that's the question, add an example if possible, or explain why it isn't possible.

Comment: Since when is explode() doing any string validations? Or what do you mean with string validations? User input should always be validated before doing anything with them anyways.

Comment: Is it possible to list other functions which don't work "properly" when given malformed UTF-8 strings? Knowing PHP I bet there's a bunch, but also typical of PHP.. I find any solid documentation on this...

Comment: PHP strings are just binary data. The character encoding only matters when you work with specific functions that assume a specific encoding (i. e., [they have an *encoding* or *charset* parameter](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Awww.php.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Ffunction+%22string+%24charset%22+OR+%22string+%24encoding%22)).

Comment: @Gumbo: Is that really true?  I haven't looked at the PHP source, but I can easily imagine a function that assumes characters are bytes.  Such a function would fail badly given two- or three-byte UTF-8 characters.

Comment: @BobBrown Maybe I should have said 'sequence of bytes' instead of 'binary data'. Many string functions are simply mapped to the C equivalents, which also work byte-wise.

Answer (score 1):

The `explode()` function does not use any encoding. It simply splits a sequence of bytes at a subsequence of bytes. Whether those bytes are valid characters in the encoding you happen to use is outside the scope of this function.

So `explode()` works the same for *any* string, be it a valid UTF-8 sequence or an invalid UTF-8 sequence.

If you want to validate the strings against a particular encoding before the split operation, you're free to use `mb_check_encoding()`.